# Icon inside material design button doesn't click

Tags: c#, wpf, button, material-design

I'm working with C# WPF and Material Design.

I have this button

```
        <Button x:Name="btnClose"
                Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.CloseDialogCommand}"
                Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignIconForegroundButton}"
                Background="White"
                BorderBrush="Transparent"
                Cursor="Hand"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                Margin="0 20 25 0">
            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Close"
                                     Foreground="Gray"
                                     Height="28"
                                     Width="28" />
            <Button.CommandParameter>
                <system:Boolean>False</system:Boolean>
            </Button.CommandParameter>
        </Button>
```

But I saw that, when the cursor is over the icon inside the button, the cursor doesn't change to the hand and the click doesn't work.

[image]

Someone knows why this is happening?

Comment: Did you check that `CanExecute` of your command returns true?. Try to remove the command binding and see if it get re-enabled. Can you post the content of your `CloseDialogCommand` ?

Comment: The problem is your choice of button style. The icon or path they're using for the close packicon creates the X as an absence.  It is not the icon and hence not the foreground. You chose MaterialDesignIconForegroundButton and it seems the inherent design is to make the foreground - the icon you choose - the only part that's click-able.

Comment: I think there is a bug in the Material Design styles because I saw that when I don't put margins in the button the problem doesn't happen, only when I define margins the issue happens. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/03c7c72f4a60b4b8b4b1d9df9cf36f3c664ead4e/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/DialogHost.cs) I was able to find this.

```
/// Routed command to be used inside dialog content to close a dialog. Use a <see cref="Button.CommandParameter"/> to indicate the result of the parameter.
/// </summary>
public static RoutedCommand CloseDialogCommand = new RoutedCommand();
```

Which mean that you should change

```
<Button.CommandParameter>
    <system:Boolean>False</system:Boolean>
</Button.CommandParameter>
```

to

```
<Button.CommandParameter>
    <system:Boolean>True</system:Boolean>
</Button.CommandParameter>
```